# Are adjoint representation matrices the generators of the Adjoint representation?

Tags: matrices, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

My question is, are the (Lie Algebra) adjoint representation matrices in general the generators of the (Lie Group) Adjoint representation (i.e. treating the Adjoint representation as a matrix Lie Group)?

My justification is that $ad(\xi) = T_e (Ad(\xi))$.

Therefore we treat the Adjoint representation as its own matrix Lie Group (living in the Lie Algebra vector space, i.e. it acts on Lie Algebra elements like $\xi$ in the above statement). Therefore, since it is a *matrix* Lie Group, we can in general define a Lie Algebra representation on it by its generating matrices (with the Lie Bracket represented by the usual matrix commutator)

The reason I ask this is because I was confused why the adjoint representation of su(2) (with the basis given below) could seemingly represent the Lie Bracket *either* by matrix-vector multiplication (with a vector in the Lie Algebra), *or* by their usual matrix commutator. (e.g. $[T_1,T_2]=T_3$ could be represented by $T_1*(0 1 0)= (0 0 1)$ *or* represented by $T_1*T_2-T_2*T_1 = T_3$)

My solution is therefore that adjoint is defined so that the matrix-vector multiplication represents the Lie Bracket but, since (by different reasoning) the basis of the adjoint are also 'raw' elements of the Lie Algebra of the Adjoint matrix Lie Group, they can also be represented by generators of the Adjoint matrix Lie Group (and therefore represent the Lie Bracket by the usual commutator).

$$ T_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}, T_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix}, T_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What I think you are noticing here is that the adjoint representation is faithful (i.e. injective) in this case (and for any semisimple Lie algebra). The Lie algebra is isomorphic to its image under the adjoint representation.

Comment: I think this stems from my confusion about exactly what the adjoint is (like in my other questions). As I understand it, a representation of a Lie Algebra must both represent its elements and its bracket (in some way). I thought that the adjoint representation defined matrix*vector multiplication to be its representation of the Lie Bracket, *not* matrix commutation. Is this wrong?

Comment: You're using matrices a lot and I think it's confusing the issue. You're implicitly using a standard representation (with a chosen basis to boot) to define a Lie algebra via matrices. If you have done this you can represent the adjoint representation as a commutator. Separately, you can choose a basis of your Lie algebra and represent the adjoint action with (much bigger) matrices in the same way as any other representation.

Comment: But my point here is that these are *not* the initial matrices I'm using to define the Lie Algebra. For su(2) here, I would use *2x2* complex matrices (generators of SU(2)) to define the Lie Algebra su(2) (specifically $L = span(\tau_1, \tau_2, \tau_3)$ where $\tau_i = i \sigma_1/2$. I would (obviously) be unsurprised that *these* matrices obey the Lie Bracket with normal matrix commutation.

Comment: However the matrices in my question are 3x3, so *not* the initial generators of SU(2). So I was surprised that their matrix commutation would represent the Lie Bracket also. However, once I realised that these are the generators of the Adjoint represntation of the SU(2) Lie *Group*, I was once again unsurprised that their matrix commutation represented the Lie Bracket (as it becomes exactly analogous to the 2x2 case in the previous comment)

Comment: Therefore my claim is that the matrix commutation representing the Lie Bracket for the matrices in the question is due to them being generators of a matrix Lie Group, and that this action is *not* how the adjoint representation was defined. (But I could be completely wrong of course)

Comment: By generators of $SU(2)$ you just mean a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. To write these as matrices you must choose a representation and a basis on the representation (there are infinitely many representations for any Lie algebra). The Lie bracket relations are more fundamental to the Lie algebra than these matrix representations. The fact that these matrices have the same Lie bracket relations is exactly what the Lie algebra homomorphism part of the definition of a representation is for.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, both of the representations of the Lie Bracket in my question work because they are both homomorphisms of the Lie Algebra, regardless of them being matrices. I think my main issue is with the precise definition of the adjoint representation (on my other question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid extended discussion in the comments I wanted to put a more full answer. I'll try to pull in a few points on other questions you have asked as well so it's all in one place. In short, yes.

First things first, there are a lot of brackets and commutators flying around so we have to be careful what we're doing.

A Lie algebra representation is a Lie algebra homomorphism $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathrm{End}(V)$ where $V$ is some vector space. The homomorphism part means that $\rho([X,Y]) = [\rho(X),\rho(Y)]$ where the bracket on the left is whatever bracket we have defined on $\mathfrak{g}$ and the one on the right is the canonical bracket given by the commutator on $\mathrm{End}(V)$. Picking a basis of $V$ allows one to write $\rho(X)$ as a $n\times n $ matrix ($n = \dim V$). If $\rho$ is faithful (aka injective) this is unique for each $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ so we can identify $\mathfrak{g}$ as a subset (indeed Lie subalgebra) of $\mathrm{End}(V)$. As I have said elsewhere, the homomorphism part of the definition of a representation guarantees that the set of matrices have the same Lie bracket relations as $\mathfrak{g}$ does.

There is a special representation where $V = \mathfrak{g}$ called the adjoint representation $ \mathrm{ad}:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathrm{End}(\mathfrak{g})$. Which is defined as follows: $\mathrm{ad}(X)$ is the linear map on $\mathfrak{g}$ with $\mathrm{ad}(X)(Y) = [X,Y]$. It is easy to see that this is a homomorphism i.e. that $\mathrm{ad}([X,Y]) = [\mathrm{ad}(X), \mathrm{ad}(Y)]$. Indeed this is just the Jacobi identity rearranged. For a semisimple Lie algebra, the adjoint representation is faithful and so we can represent the Lie algebra by matrices in this case. Note now we are representing elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ both as $\dim\mathfrak{g}\times\dim\mathfrak{g}$ matrices and as $\dim\mathfrak{g} \times 1$ vectors simultaneously. So we have our original element $X$, its adjoint image $T_X = ad(X)$ viewed as a big matrix and it viewed as a vector $v_X$ to make that big matrix make sense. Then $[X,Y] = T_X*v_Y$ under the appropriate identifications.

Tying this to the Lie group story, the Adjoint group is defined as the image under the Adjoint representation of any Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Thus it is automatically linear (i.e. a matrix group) as a subgroup of $GL(\mathfrak{g})$. Then you can generate the the Adjoint action using your chosen basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ viewed as $\dim\mathfrak{g} \times \dim\mathfrak{g}$ matrices if you so desire.

More generally, this works any time there is a valid Lie group representation. Note a Lie algebra representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ doesn't imply that a specific corresponding Lie group $G$ has a valid representation. The adjoint representation is special in that every Lie group has an Adjoint representation. For other representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ not all Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ also have a representation there. E.g. the special orthogonal group has no spin representations and the adjoint group often doesn't act on the original "vector" representations.

Comment: Alex, note that $ad([X,Y])$ is something very different from $ad_X Y$ (which maybe should be denoted $(ad(X))(Y)$ here). The first is an *endomorphism* of $\mathfrak g$ (you can still plug an element of $\mathfrak g$ into it). The second is an *element* of $\mathfrak g$. This distinction has little to do with choice of basis.

Comment: But yes, *if* the bracket of $\mathfrak g$ itself happens to be given by a commutator already (e.g. if $\mathfrak g$ is already given by matrices), then of course the element $ad_X Y \in \mathfrak g$ happens to be "writable as commutator" too, although this commutator (of matrices, say), has little to do with the commutator in its endomorphism ring (and even if everything is written out as matrices, they have very different sizes).

Comment: By the way, the kernel of the adjoint representation is always the centre of the Lie algebra. And maybe it is a good exercise to see what the adjoint representation "is", to write it out for some easy two- and three-dimensional Lie algebras, some with trivial and some with non-trivial centre.

Comment: The reason I am so careful about faithful reps is that otherwise two elements of the Lie algebra represent the same linear map on $V$. So we can represent the elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ by matrices, but some of them are the same matrices. We capture the action but not the whole Lie algebra

Comment: On second reading (which I needed to get rid of many of my faulty assumptions) this answer really is excellent @Callum thanks. So, in a nutshell, I was correct that ad generates Ad but this was *not* the reason why both matrix-commutation and matrix-vector multiplication worked in my OP. (Instead, this comes from from the fact that ad is special in that it is defined *on the Lie Algebra*)

Comment: The only remaining part of your answer I don't get is the very final sentence. I'm assuming you're just saying that so(3) has (spin) Lie Algebra representations, $r$, which cannot be written as $r = T_e (R)$ for $R$ a representation of SO(3)? Then I have no idea what the last bit about vector representations means

Comment: Yes exactly, there are no spin representations of $SO_n$. The "vector representation" is a loose term for the representation you are probably thinking of when you define $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ etc. You imagine them acting on an n-dimensional space. The adjoint group of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is $PSL_n \equiv SL_n/Z$, the projective special linear group. This doesn't have a representation on the same vector space (although it does act  as you would imagine on the corresponding projective space)

Comment: Thanks. Although later in my Groups course lecture notes they state this. “A linear map f from the Lie Algebra to itself is the tangent map of a group homomorphism F iff f is a Lie Algebra homomorphism”. Doesn’t this imply there is in fact always a corresponding Lie Group rep for each Lie Algebra rep?

Comment: That is only about maps from $\mathfrak{g}$ to itself. More generally we only have one direction guaranteed: a Lie group homomorphism $G\to H$ differentiates to a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$. The converse is true if we make the extra assumption that $G$ is simply connected. So the simply connected group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ has a rep for every rep of $\mathfrak{g}$ but other groups with that Lie algebra may have fewer.